# SQL Not Null vs Constraint

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I did try searching but this seems like one of those "hit or miss" questions in getting the search term right.

We have a vendor who's changed all their columns from "Not Null" to "Null" and then adding "Not Null" Constraints:

`ADD CONSTRAINT [ColNN01] CHECK ([ColName] IS NOT NULL)`

When we asked them about it, they said it was to make future maintenance easier when changing the null-ability on a column.

From what I've searched, performance of "Not Null" vs Constraint would be similar (if not identical), but I'm guessing the catch would come in the case of having to `ALTER` the column to change the null-ability vs adding / removing the `CONSTRAINT`?  Is there a time when you wouldn't be able to simply `ALTER` the column?

Comment: I can't think of any way that this would "ease maintenance". In either case, when deciding to make a column `not null`, it will require a scan of all existing rows' null bitmaps. And making a column `null` able will, in either case, be a metadata only operation. If you want to persue it further, the only thing I could suggest would be to ask for further *evidence* that this provides a maintenance benefit. Especially when it's likely to confuse any normal tooling that uses table metadata to explore this schema.

Comment: Alter the column from not null to null should be just as easy and available as removing the check constraint. Just like Damien, I don't see any maintenance benefit.

Comment: I 2nd Damien's and Zohar's comments -- its difficult to conceive of any maintenance that this facilitates.  I would think that this would make development and debugging more difficult.  When defining a table, it is much less work to type "NOT NULL" at the end of column than it is to define a constraint.  Further, constraints have to have names.  Sql-Server makes up cryptic names if you don't provide them.  So, this will require a consistent naming scheme, or error messages will complain about some cryptic constraint being violated.

Comment: Thanks for all the info guys, I felt the same way but thought I'd clarify, just in case there was something I wasn't actually noting.